# Unknown symbol in logic diagram

Tags: symbol

I am trying to make sense of this logic diagram for an ON Semiconductor 7-segment display driver. What is this logic symbol? I have never seen it before, and I have not seen it anywhere online after looking for about an hour.

[image]

Here it is in the larger logic diagram:

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, this schematic is pretty confusing even if you know what a transmission gate is. I think the structures on the left side are equivalent to latches, represented in an unnecessarily low-level way.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right, the datasheet does mention 4-bit storage latches. Some of these diagrams are driving me crazy.